# stdout log files from an executable - where do they go when I start the program by clicking on its icon?

Tags: unity, logging

When starting an executable from the terminal various messages are printed in the terminal.

My question is, where are these messages logged when you launch the application without a terminal (by double clicking on the icon)?

I looked in `/var/log` but I don't know which file contains them.

For example, a custom application that is started from the Unity launcher.

Comment: As long as one doesn't manually redirect the output, I think it's simply discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go to `/dev/null` unless you change the startup program that that icon is starting to log it elsewhere.

---

Something like this:

```
sh -c "command > ~/file.log"
```

Comment: Can you change it globally?

Comment: Globally? No? And you would have a disc full notice rather quickly if you'd reroute all messages. Next to that: wth would you!?

Comment: True... Forgot about that. Thx. How can you change the startup program to log its stdout somewhere? I can write a shell script that redirects its output. Is there a more elegant way? Something for instance you can edit in /usr/share/applications/{app}.desktop?

Comment: Nope the only way is a shell script. Launchers do not understand && (chaining commands)  or ~ (expanding to home).